# Is there a Postgres json function(s) to limit results and do

Tags: postgresql, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I am pretty inexperience working with json in Postgres and it is making getting the data I need out very difficult. Using the query below I can see that `callflow` gives me the times for each section of the call. Can I get `times` where `hangup_time` is grater than 0? Ideally I just need time in seconds between `created_time` and `hangup_time` for each row.

```
select
    xml_cdr_uuid,
    json->'callflow'
from fusionpbx.public.v_xml_cdr
where start_stamp > now() - '1 day'::interval;
```

which gives me arrays of times like this for each row.

```
[
    {
        "times":
        {
            "hangup_time": "1588604603083829",
            "bridged_time": "1588604592603811",
            "created_time": "1588604575783849",
            "answered_time": "1588604575803817",
            "progress_time": "1588604575803817",
            "transfer_time": "0",
            "last_hold_time": "0",
            "resurrect_time": "0",
            "hold_accum_time": "0",
            "progress_media_time": "0",
            "profile_created_time": "1588604582343873"
        },
        "extension": {...},
        "@attributes": {...},
        "caller_profile": {...},
    },
    {
        "times":
        {
            "hangup_time": "0",
            "bridged_time": "0",
            "created_time": "1588604575783849",
            "answered_time": "1588604575803817",
            "progress_time": "1588604575803817",
            "transfer_time": "1588604582343873",
            "last_hold_time": "0",
            "resurrect_time": "0",
            "hold_accum_time": "0",
            "progress_media_time": "0",
            "profile_created_time": "1588604575783849"
        },
        "extension": {...},
        "@attributes": {...},
        "caller_profile": {...},
    },
    {
        "times":
        {
            "hangup_time": "0",
            "bridged_time": "0",
            "created_time": "1588604575783849",
            "answered_time": "0",
            "progress_time": "0",
            "transfer_time": "1588604575783849",
            "last_hold_time": "0",
            "resurrect_time": "0",
            "hold_accum_time": "0",
            "progress_media_time": "0",
            "profile_created_time": "1588604575783849"
        },
        "extension": {...},
        "@attributes": {...},
        "caller_profile": {...},
    }
]
```

Comment: So you want the returned JSON array reduced to array elements where the key `hangup_time` is greater than zero? Or do you only want to have rows that contain at least one array element where that value is greater than zero? Or do you want rows where all array elements have a value greater than zero

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the end result that I am going for is to have a value `post_transfer_time` which is a seconds difference between `created_time` and `hangup_time`. Thanks!

Comment: you will need to extract this information from 'callflow' using `json_array_elements` and `->>`